# Powershell: Re-create RDS Remote Apps by Looping?

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I'm stumped.  I can usually take the output of one powershell command and use it as the input to another powershell command.  For example:

`Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -MaxSendSize 40MB`

This will loop through every mailbox and then set the maximum send size to 40 MB in Exchange 2007.

...but the same doesn't work with get-rdremoteapp and new-rdremoteapp.

`Get-RDRemoteApp | new-rdremoteapp -collectionname APPSNEW -connectionbroker edge-1.mydom.local`

The goal of this command is that we are preparing to Migrate from a Windows 2012 RDS environment on virtual servers to a Windows 2012 *R2* environment on physical servers.

On the virtual 'edge' server, I should be able to get all the RD Remote Apps, loop through them, and then use the 'new-rdremoteapp' command to create them on the new 'edge-1' server.

What actually happens is the command runs and creates the 1st remote app, then exits without an error.  It doesn't process the apps in the list.

I think I need to use foreach-object, but after reading the docs and playing around, I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an easy out.  I had to specify a bunch of parameters like so:

`Get-RDRemoteApp | foreach-object -process {new-rdremoteapp -collectionname APPSNEW -connectionbroker edge-1.mydom.local -displayname $_.displayname -filepath $_.filepath -alias $_.alias -commandlinesetting $_.commandlinesetting -usergroups $_.usergroups}`

Time to find a job that has more bash scripting... ;)